# .NET 3.5 SP1 Installation Error

Tags: .net-3.5, installation, windows-xp-sp2

I have Windows XP Service Pack-2 on my PC. When I tried to install .NET 3.5 SP1 from following link:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22
then during the installation part, the setup shows me an error that `regsvcs.exe` application Error and installation failed!

Comment: this post should be moved other Stack exchange sites I think....

Comment: Anyways is there `windows installer 3.1` in your system? If not install it and try ...

Comment: yes i have windows installer 4 installed. .NET Setup successfully downloaded whole package but this error shows up in installation process. any ideas?

Comment: you need `windows installer 3.1` only I think - http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21#instructions , not `windows installer 4`

Comment: I installed windows installer 3.1 but same issue!!!
Error is a dialog box with title "RegSvcs.exe Application Error", and body contains "The application failed to initialize properly. Click on OK to terminate application"

Comment: you restarted the system and checked right?

Comment: try setting compatibility flag on the setup file properties (right click on the file) and try to install...

Comment: this blog has lots of info on `regsvcs.exe`, but its for .NET Framework 2.0 - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2006/11/25/disabling-services-with-msconfig-to-work-around-setup-failures.aspx